# Can I make a function case-sensitive in php?

Tags: php, function, case-sensitive

PHP functions are not case sensitive , but if I want them to be is there **any** way to do it ??

```
function FIRe()
{
   return "FIR Emergency";
}

function FIRE()
{
    return "FIRE OUT THERE";
}
FIRe();
```

**Note:** Again saying, I know they are case-insensitive, is there any way to make them case sensitive?

Comment: No, luckily there isn't. Your example makes a pretty good proof against case-sensitive identifiers.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I know they are case insensitive , my question is "Is there a way to make them case sensitive?"

Comment: @Rizier123 some case like the one in code snippet above

Comment: The link and the information contained there answer your question @DarshanJain

Comment: @DarshanJain why would you want to do such a horrible thing? Why would you want several functions that do different things but share the same name apart from the case? Are you some kind of monster?

Comment: Like using any function like `create_function()` or such

Comment: You could store the function name inside of a case sensitive variable and `$FIRe()`/`$FIRE()`. You could also likely namespace them or put them in separate classes.

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn can you post it as an answer with some examples plz ?